# Displaying return value of void type

Tags: java, void

```
package email;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Email email = new Email("833","388","How are you?");
    someMethod(email);
  }

  private static void someMethod(Email email) {
    System.out.println(email.trimLines());
  }
}
```

I have a question on displaying return value of a void type. So trimLines is a void type method. I don't see how you can display a void type method because the method return nothing so there is nothing to display. Since `println` takes a string type this would cause an error.

I couldn't find any method in `System.out` that would display a void type. This was specified in my assignment to display return value of the void method. I think my teacher made a mistake but may be there is something that will work with void type.

Can anyone confirm if my teacher made a mistake or is there a method that can display the void type?

Comment: So your teacher told you to print the return value of a void method? Please leave that school/tutor immediately, and join a good one.

Comment: You are right I should leave the school, It turn out that I was not misinterpreting anything when I ask her she apologized for that the problem was written incorrectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*void* means that the method returns *nothing*, not even null. So maybe there's really an error in your assignment.

We don't know the implemenation of your `EMail` class. So `trimlines()` may affect the inner state of your email instance ("the mail body"). Maybe you have to call `trimlines()` first on the object and print *the email* in a second step.

Comment: yes that what i thought too I just want to confirm if my teacher made a mistake

Comment: thank i was misinterpret the question ask on the assignment, the assignment ask to call first then to display the return value.